# OpenGL - Display video a stream of the desktop on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, screen-capture, artoolkit

So I am trying to figure out how get a video feed (or screenshot feed if I must) of the Desktop using OpenGL in Windows and display that in a 3D environment. I plan to integrate this with ARToolkit to make essentially a virtual screen. The only issue is that I have tried manually getting the pixels in OpenGl, but I have been unable to properly display them in a 3D environment?

I apologize in advance that I do not have minimum runnable code, but due to all the dependencies and whatnot trying to get an ARToolkit code running would be far from minimal. How would I capture the desktop on Windows and display it in ARToolkit?

BONUS: If you can grab each desktop from the 'virtual' desktops in Windows 10, that would be an excellent bonus!

Alternative: If you know another AR library that renders differently, or allows me to achieve the same effect, I would be grateful.

Comment: Actually, that is quite a difficult request. OpenGL has nothing to do with the windows desktop. But conceptually, the problem is even worse: as you actually draw on the same desktop, you would get a feedback loop. AMD has the [Display Output Post Processing (DOPP)](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/firepro-sdk/dopp/) extensions, which can do what you want. But it is only supported on AMD's FiroPro series on workstation cards, so far from a general solution...

Comment: I am aware of the feedback loop, normally I would stream it to another desktop to solve this issue. I am just trying to see if it's feasible, and if it is not finding an alternate way to implement perhaps via a fork of ARToolkit that takes DirectX or some other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different problems here:

a) Make an augmentation that plays video

b) Stream the desktop to somewhere else

For playing video on an augmentation you basically need to have a texture that gets updated on each frame. I recall that ARToolkit for Unity has an example that plays video.However.

Streaming the desktop to the other device is a problem of its own. There are tools that do screen recording, but you probably don't want that.

It sounds to me that what you want to do it to make a VLC viewer and put that into an augmentation. If I am correct, I suggest you to start by looking at existing open source VLC viewers.